# Find closest span element and change the CSS Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following on my page

```
<h5 class="text-center" id="findStore" style="width:260px">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#@item.ProductId" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="@item.ProductId" style="color: @item.ProductTextColor;font-size:19px;text-decoration: none;" class="text-center">
         <span class="text-center" style="margin-left:14%">FIND A STORE</span> 
         <span id="chevvy" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></span>
    </a>
</h5>
```

What I would like to happen is when the user clicks "Find Store" the span tag with the Id chevvy needs to be referenced and I need to change the class chevron-down to chevron-up which I'm trying to do with the following code

```
$('h5:not(#nutritionInfo)').click(function () {

if ($(this).find('span').hasClass("glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down")) {
    $(this).find('span').removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down");
    $(this).find('span').addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up");
} else {
    $(this).find('span').removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up");
    $(this).find('span').addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down");
}
});
```

But with the above code, it reference's "Find Store" and applies a chevron to it so it displays two.

How can I reference the other span tag with the Id chevvy and change the chevron on it?

Comment: Is the #chevvy item just there for the icon?

Comment: So who down voted? any explanation in to why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this : You can find span using `glyphicon` class selector and then remove / add class.

**NOTE** - You have used span `id=chevvy` and if you are having multiple such spans then please make sure that you must use unique id for each DOM element.

```
$('h5:not(#nutritionInfo)').click(function () {
  var span = $(this).find('.glyphicon');
  if ($(span).hasClass("glyphicon-chevron-down")) {
    $(span).removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-down").addClass("glyphicon-chevron-up");
  } else {
    $(span).addClass("glyphicon-chevron-down").removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-up");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `find('span')` is finding all spans, but you only want to touch the one. Narrow it down by adding more selectors, like `find('span.glyphicon')`.

Incidentally, you could leave the `glyphicon` class alone, and make use of jQuery's `toggleClass` feature to toggle both `-up` and `-down` without all the if-else:

```
$('h5:not(#nutritionInfo)').click(function () {
    $(this).find('span.glyphicon').
        toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-down glyphicon-chevron-up');
});
```

You might also consider using a pseudoclass instead of an id to determine which h5 elements get this behavior. For example, you could have a bunch of these

```
<h5 class="toggle-my-chevron">...</h5>
<h5 class="toggle-my-chevron">...</h5>
```

All controlled by one of these

```
$('.toggle-my-chevron').click(function () {
    $(this).find('span.glyphicon').
        toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-down glyphicon-chevron-up');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to optimise your HTML and your CSS as you have redundant HTML in your snippet - This will help clear up the JS as well. Here's a quick example of what you could do:

**HTML**

```
<h5 class="text-center" id="findStore">
  <a href="#" class="">FIND A STORE</a>
</h5>
```

**CSS**

Apply the icon image via CSS eg.

```
h5 a {padding-right: 10px; background: transparent url('chevron-down.png') 100% 0 no-repeat}
h5 a.active {background: transparent url('chevron-up.png') 100% 0 no-repeat}
```

**JS/JQUERY**

```
$('h5 a').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  return false;
});
```